# Is it possible to combine more tr commands?

Tags: linux, bash, pipeline, tr

I use tr command 3 times sequentially in this case:

```
tr -d [[:digit:]] | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | tr -cd '[:alnum:]\nčšž'
```

Is it possible to combine 3 tr commands in 1 tr command?
Or is there some way, how to do that faster?

Comment: The first and third you can definitely combine, just by changing the `:alnum:` to `:alpha:` in the third and deleting the first.

Comment: that said, if you're calling this from bash for a short string, your *best* performance will likely be had by eliminating `tr` altogether and using shell builtins instead; the startup costs (to start `tr`) will exceed what you gain from tr's faster runtime performance compared to built-in operations.

Comment: ...which specific bash version are you using?

Comment: And if you're processing a file, you can combine them all with `sed`.

Comment: You should use `sed` since `tr` only works with bytes. `tr -cd '[:alnum:]\nčšž'` doesn't do what you expect (try passing it `ď` and watch it spit out an invalid UTF-8 character).

Comment: I musn't use sed and I use linux mint.

Comment: "musn't use sed" -- is this for a class?

Comment: @Charles Duffy yes, is it anything wrong with it? I've just finished my work, I just want to get it faster ;)

Comment: The biggest improvements will be had by reducing the number of times this pipeline is run -- so if you can run it just once for your entire input stream, that will be *far* more efficient than running it once per line. However, you aren't showing enough work in your question to allow useful contributions of that type, since we can't see the flow of the code doing the invocation, and thus can't make useful suggestions about how to optimize it to do so less frequently.

Comment: you fully answered on my question right down here, man, thank you!

Comment: (Glad that helped! BTW, "using linux mint" doesn't really answer "which version of bash?" -- any distro has lots of different releases, and folks on SO can't be expected to know which bash version Distro X version Y.Z shipped anyhow; in the future, to answer that question, consider sharing the output of `echo "$BASH_VERSION"`).

Comment: so you will be happy with that:
linux mint 4.3.8(1)-release ?

Comment: ooh, excellent -- that's a nice shiny new bash; I'm glad to hear Mint is using it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume you're piping a string through bash:

```
# this is your starting code
f() { tr -d [[:digit:]] | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | tr -cd '[:alnum:]\nčšž'; }

# defining a test variable
s='hello123WORLD456'$'\n''čšž'

f <<<"$s" # writes "helloworld", a newline, then "čšž"
```

...can trivially be changed by combining first and third, since they're both performing the same basic operation (deleting all characters in a given set -- even if in one of the two cases the set is defined in an exclusionary manner):

```
# this behaves the same way
f() { tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | tr -cd '[:alpha:]\nčšž'; }
```

...however, if running a modern bash release, you can do the same thing with a pair of parameter expansions, without any of the overhead of running `tr` at all:

```
s_lowercase=${s,,}
s_alpha=${s_lowercase//[![:alpha:]čšž]/}
echo "$s_alpha"
```